# how to find the smallest n values in a distributed dask array

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I have a distributed dask array with shape (2400,2400) with chunksize (100,100). I thought I could use topk(-n) to find the smallest n values. However, it appears to return an array of shape (2400,n), so it looks like it finds the smallest n in each row.Is there a way to use topk to get the smallest n values across all rows (entire array)?

One idea is to call topk twice, once for each axis.

```
>>> dist
dask.array<pow, shape=(2400, 2400), dtype=float64, chunksize=(100, 100)>
>>> dist.topk(-5,axis=0).topk(-5,axis=1).compute()
array([[   0.        , 2620.09503644, 2842.15200157, 2955.08409356,
        3163.49458669],
       [3660.67698657, 3670.4457495 , 3700.09837707, 3717.09052889,
        4002.86497399],
       [4125.89820524, 4139.44658137, 4250.50420539, 4331.01304547,
        4402.14606754],
       [4328.22966119, 4378.25193428, 4507.94409903, 4522.4913488 ,
        4555.06860541],
       [4441.58755402, 4560.95625938, 4576.39333974, 4682.06215251,
        4765.11531865]])
```

Answer (score 1):

> One idea is to call topk twice, once for each axis.

Sounds good to me!

You might consider flattening the array first, but I can't see an advantage to this to what you've already found.

```
x.flatten().topk(...)
```

Comment: Just confirming that x.topk(-n,axis=0).topk(-n,axis=1).compute() gives you the smallest n-squared elements in the Dask array?

Comment: Oh, I have no idea.  I assumed that you had tried that and that it worked.  There is an easy way to find out!

Comment: The answer is "not necessarily." One pathological case is where the smallest values in the array are all in the same row. Then topk(-n, axis=0) selects the smallest n of those, and the remaining row elements are not considered further by topk(-n,axis=1)